# Message routing based on rules

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mqtt, messaging, vert.x

I'm looking for Java server technologies that suit the following scenario:

Client X sends a message -> some server component decides, based on certain rules e.g.`if message from client X and content equals Y, forward message to Client Z (or a group of clients)`.

Client Z (or the first one of the group that read the message) confirms the message and takes further (physical) actions.

The messages should be sent reliably to the clients and logged/stored somewhere to be able to retrace what client sent what kind of message and what client confirmed it.

There are max. 200 clients and maybe around 200-300 Messages per hour so performance/throughput is not "that" important.

Possible Technologies:

- Server: Java EE (e.g. Wildfly Swarm) or vert.x ...
- Clients: JavaScript web apps on Android tablets (Web Socket are available)
- Storage: MySQL, NoSQL, ...

To me it looks like an MQTT Broker could be suited for this on server side... What do you think? The biggest question mark to me is how/where to implement the routing logic (`if message from client X then forward to...`) and logging/storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It strikes me that setting up content based routing kind of defeats the entire publisher->broker->subscriber model that MQTT is based on. My understanding is that most MQTT brokers assume that the processing will take place on clients, not in the broker itself. I assume you could implement it but this would be my (language agnostic) suggestion instead.

1. Client X parses the message internally and, if it has content Y, it sends it to topic A.
2. As Client Z knows that any message on topic A has the content it wants, Client Z subscribes to topic A and receives content Y.

If there is some absolute requirement that the processing not be handled by Client X you could do something like this instead:

1. Client X sends the message to topic X.
2. Client A is subscribed to topic X and parses the message looking for Y.
3. If Y is found Client A publishes a message to topic Z.
4. Client Z is subscribed to topic Z and receives content Y.

This approach is a bit clunky but it suits the logic and structure of MQTT.

Comment: Exzellent. This is exactely what I am looking for, Are there any ready to use solutions that implement such a message routing logic?